# How to know what time is it in user's region django?

Tags: django, date, django-models, time, django-views

I have django web app with authentication. I want to see on users profile when he joined(created account).

I have created model field like:

```
joined_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

but it gives me utc time. Which is 2 hours behind our time. And if someone from China would be able to create an account he would have bad experience with that too. **So I want to find out what time it is in user's region and display that on field.**

Thanks for help:)

Answer (score 1):

you can use: django-tz-detect 0.4.0

[docs](https://pypi.org/project/django-tz-detect/#description)